# SQLite doesn't write a column

Tags: android

I do this:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String sql = "insert into "+getTableName()+("+DatabaseHelper.PRODUCT_MARK+",
         "+DatabaseHelper.PRODUCT_NAME+") 
          VALUES ('"+input.getMark()+"','"+input.getName()+"')";
System.out.println(sql);
getDatabase().execSQL(sql); 

dbHelper.close();
```

The system print

```
12-14 16:53:33.857: I/System.out(1350): insert into product (pMark,name) 
            VALUES ('aaaaa ','zz')
```

But when I read from db the property mark is not valorized...
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you pasted the code correctly? It looks as if you have some quote characters (") missing, which would cause compile errors. See the funny syntax highlighting of your code snippet?

Comment: If I am looking at this correctly you seem to be missing a quotation directly after `+getTableName()+`, but you should have received an error on compilation

Comment: They showed us their `System.out.println` output, so any compilation errors are simply in his formatting of the code above and not within the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

`getWritableDatabase` returns a `Database` object and should be used as follows:

`Database db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(context);`

Then you can execute your SQL with:

`db.execSQL(...);`